# Kafka message publishing failure for random valid messages , how to fix this issue?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka, jms-topic

We are using kafka in our app , we are sending too many many messages , each message is small in size , what i mean message size is not issue , is their any issue if you try to publish toooo many message to kafka topic  that some messages to failed to publish ?

```
"Publishing error messages to kafka topic failed400 "
```

Is their any kafka config that we can set so that this issue we can overcome ?

Note : Too many calls , i mean one send method call , one message .

As mentioned each message is not too large , given below the sample

```
{
    "error_details": [
        {
            "error_number": "123",
            "error_message": "how are you",
            "error_sequence": "12345"
        },
        {
            "error_number": "123",
            "error_message": "how are you",
            "error_sequence": "12345"
        },
        {
            "error_number": "123",
            "error_message": "how are you",
            "error_sequence": "12345"
        },
        {
            "error_number": "123",
            "error_message": "how are you",
            "error_sequence": "12345"
        }

    ]
}
```

this is max size

Comment: How does number of messages sent per call affect your problem.  In other words, does the problem seem to be too many messages or too many calls?

Comment: Yes too many calls , one call , one message we are sending

Comment: What is the kafka error message ?

Comment: @LijuJohn , i mentioned in the question

Comment: @Bravo  - I mean what type of Kafka Exception ( kafka exception class name to be precise)

Comment: What is your producer config setting for batch.size and linger.ms?  These control batching of messages per send. Max.block.ms and max.request.size also play a role.

Comment: @ChrisGerken  batch.size: 16384    and   linger.ms : 1

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how large your messages are, but I'd try increasing linger.ms

The linger.ms is the number of milliseconds that the producer will wait to see if another message is sent.  If another message is sent within that time then both messages will be batched in a single call.  That might help your situation.

The batch.size setting gives the max size of a batch of messages.  Even if the linger duration is still in effect, reaching a combined message size greater than the batch.size will send the batch immediately.

Just don't set linger.ms too high.  Nothing will be sent until the end of that duration is reached, unless of course the batched messages together excess batch.size

Comment: we have already set linger,ms  as   1 , means 1 milli second , so do we need to increase this ?  how much is good ?

Comment: It's a trade-off.  A value of 1000 would mean that you'd send batched messages only every second (unless batch.size is exceeded before the second is up).  Not sure what your SLA'a are, but a temporary setting of 1000 would let you see if there's any improvement.  Once you see what 1000 would do, try lowering it until you start to see exceptions under load again.  Then from that point try increasing batch.size and lowering linger.ms until you're happy with how your app is running.

Comment: @Bravo Have you had any luck?